# Why does FactoryGirl(:build) work with Sorcery, but not FactoryGirl(:create)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, sorcery

I'm trying to setup tests for my Rails app. I'm using Factory Girl and Rspec with Sorcery for authentication. For some reason this test doesn't pass:

```
describe "User" do
  it "has a valid the factory" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user.should be_valid 
  end
end
```

But this one does:

```
describe "User" do
  it "has a valid the factory" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    user.should be_valid 
  end
end
```

The error on the failing test said that the password did not match its confirmation, so it seems like this has something to do with how Sorcery handles password encryption.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Does it have to do with how Sorcery encrypts the passwords? Is it intentional, or a bug?

Comment: It appears that I can't create a user with FactoryGirl.create. The only thing I've been able to get to pass is to build a user and then fill out the signup form. Is this a limitation of sorcery?

Comment: I think you simply have a validation issue. `.create` is calling save, while `.build` is not and the later object is valid since it hasn't passed validation yet because you haven't called `#save` on it.

Comment: I am getting an error saying the password and password_confirmation don't match when I switch the test to FactoryGirl.create. Here's the error: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/d8607ad83d530558a011. So does this have to do with how Sorcery is salting the passwords? Because the password and confirmation are the same. Here's my user factory: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/ac401e08a45ebb7b884f. I am also able to create a user through the browser just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` is valid because the built object really is a valid object, though existing in memory only.

The `create` is not valid because `save` failed.

The reason of saving failure, I think, should be about Activation. I don't have experience on Sorcery but Devise only, the principles are similar. It seems Sorcery ask for activation by default according to its README.

It's easy to fix it directly in factory definition, by adding a hook of activation after creation.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # other fields
    after(:create) { |user| user.activate! }
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be the right direction. But I don't have the Sorcery activation module enabled. I tried adding `after(:create) { |user| user.activate! }` as well as `activation_state  "active"` to my user factory but I got a no method error. I assume this is because the activation model isn't enabled.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly, they should be something preventing your saving. You can try FactoryGirl.create(:user) in console and check the response.

Comment: Well FactoryGirl.create(:user) worked just fine: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/e0d6e34de8f24bba12cc

Comment: Ok, I can get the test to pass if I remove password_confirmation  "password" from my user factory. Now it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5e06e1f8a1567b5250f4. But I also had to remove the length validation on the password. Previously I had this validation: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/b33d02dfb62886a7af44. But now it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a59c36f685a748b3561b. So does the active record length validation not work with sorcery / rspec / capybara? The user signup works fine in the browser with the length validation, just not FactoryGirl.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly, I checked your FactoryGirl.define again(https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/ac401e08a45ebb7b884f). Comparing with my project, it seems `password_confirmation` is unnecessary in `define` because it's not a real attr. You can try it again with removing of this field and recovering length validation.

Comment: Thanks Billy. I removed the password_confirmation from my factory and I'm still getting this error `Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)`. FactoryGirl.create(:user) will pass if I remove the password length validation in my User model. But that doesn't seem like the correct solution and length validation works properly when I test it manually in the browser. Here's my factory now: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/82d36d43a85c88ee30e5. That password is 8 characters.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is causing the issue: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/416

Comment: Update on this, if I add `->{ crypted_password.blank? }` to my User validation like this: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5627723, then it passes. But I don't understand why. Here's where that idea came from: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/125#issuecomment-18250206

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to add user definition to FactoryGirl:

```
factory :user do
  ...
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

And your model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  validates :password, confirmation: true  
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And it definitely works.

There is nothing with activation or encryption.